# Any idea about what does this image represent in control systems?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

[image]

I just need a hint , I know it's out of context but that's how I found it in a Facebook group, I thought someone might have seen this before, I study automation and I know that Kp is the proportional gain in a PID controller

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a trajectory on a phase plane